# flex/bison interpreting numbers as floats

Tags: bison, yacc, lex, flex-lexer

I'm trying a implement a flex/bison calculator which can do floating point arithmetic. My flex code looks like this

```
%{
#include "calc.tab.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

void yyerror(char *s);
%}

digit [0-9]
integer {digit}+
real ({digit}+[.]{digit}*)|({digit}*[.]{digit}+)
exp ({integer}|{real})[eE]-?{integer}

%%

({integer}|{real}|{exp}) { yylval = atof(yytext); return NUMBER; }
[-+*/\n]                 { return *yytext; }
[ \t\v\f\r]              { }
.                        { yyerror("Unknown Character"); }

%%

int yywrap(void)
{
  return 1;
}
```

And my bison code looks like this

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>

typedef double YYSTYPE;
#define YYSTYPE_IS_DECLARED

void yyerror(char *s);
extern char *yytext;
extern int yylineno;
%} 

%token NUMBER

%left '+' '-'
%left '*' '/'

%%

program: program expr '\n' { printf("%g\n", $2); }
       | program '\n'
       |
       ;
expr: expr '+' expr { $$ = $1 + $3; }
    | expr '-' expr { $$ = $1 - $3; }
    | expr '*' expr { $$ = $1 * $3; }
    | expr '/' expr { $$ = $1 / $3; }
    | NUMBER { $$ = $1; }
    ;

%%

void yyerror(char *s)
{
  fprintf(stderr, "error: %s at %s, line %d\n", s, yytext, yylineno);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  yyparse();

  return 0;
}
```

This doesn't produce the right output. Even though the lexer interprets the strings as doubles and stores them properly in the `yylval` variable, when the parser adds up the numbers, it spits out only `0.0000`. However, if I declare `yylval` as a union through the `%union` directive consisting of only one `double lf_val;` variable, and store the `atof` output in this field of `yylval` in the lexer and also declare `%token <lf_val> NUMBER` and `%type <lf_val> expr` in the parser, things seem to work.

But, why doesn't the straightforward method of `typedef`ing `YYSTYPE` work? I also tried `#define YYSTYPE double`. That didn't work either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Concerning `%code`, [Bison's documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#g_t_0025code-Summary) states:

```
%code requires [...] is the best place to override Bison's default YYSTYPE
and YYLTYPE definitions.
```

So juste add the following at the top of you bison file:

```
%code requires
  {
    #define YYSTYPE double
  }
```

You will also want to remove these two lines:

```
typedef double YYSTYPE;
#define YYSTYPE_IS_DECLARED
```

Note that YYSTYPE_IS_DECLARED is, as far as I know, not documented anywhere and is thus for Bison's internal use only.

If you are not familiar with the use of Bison's `%code` directives over simple `%{` prologues, you might find [this section of the documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Prologue-Alternatives) interesting to read.

Comment: Thanks @yroeht. I noticed that enclosing the `#define` inside the `%code requires { }` directive generated the definition of YYSTYPE in the `.h` file too which was included by the lexer. Thus, the lexer was writing into an integer variable, while the parser was reading from a double!